# Crystal Reports Printing blank page

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-server

I have a crystal report which is printing a blank page and printing the report fine, but just with this additional page.

Done my research, ticked, unticked and added correct formula into the 'New Page After' option, not on last record formula etc, but its still printing the blank page.

Here is my Section expert details

- Report Header (Ticked - Free-form [greyed], New Page After [Greyed])
- Report Header a (ticked - Free-form, Suppress, Keep together)
- Report Header b (Ticked - Free-form Placement, Suppress, Keep Together)
- Page Header (Ticked - Free-form placement, Suppress, Keep together [greyed])
- Group Header #1: MP_DOCUMENT.DOCNUM - A (Ticked - Free-form, Keep together)
- Group header #2: MP_DOCUMENT.ID - A (Ticked - Free-form placement, Suppress, Keep together)
- Details (Ticked - Free-form placement, Keep together)
- Group Footer #2: MP_DOCUMENT.ID - A (Ticked - Free-form placement, Keep together)
- Group Footer #1: MP_DOCUMENT.DOCNUM - A (Ticked - Free-form placement, supress, Reset Page number after, Keep together)
- Page Footer  (Ticked - Free-form placement, Keep together [Greyed out])
- Report Footer (Ticked - Free-form placement, Suppress, New page after [greyed out], keep together)

If you have any ideas, all help is appreciated.

Thanks all.

Comment: which section occupying the blank page in your crystal reports?

Comment: Sorry i don't understand you're question, do you mean which section is occupying the blank page in my cp? or?

Comment: yes which section occupying the blank page so that we can set the section not to extend to another page

Comment: how would i find this out sorry? i'm not to keen on crystal reports, all i understand is what i have above.

Comment: Add a dummy field on each section that is not suppressed and whihch is different in each section and run the report again. Then on the blank page you will know which field is printing and know which section it is that is causing the blank page.

Answer (score 1):

I think the option Keep Object Together can be the reason.

As this will keep the sections together and will not allow some lines on one page and other remaining details on the next page, instead it will shift all of the section together.

- Check the section before which the blank page is appearing.
- Try unchecking that section Keep Object Together option
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delayed response.

Think others will find this useful.

Some of the control/controls in the report might have exceeded the report area

Please right click on the blank report area and choose page setup.

try setting the **left top right bottom** margins to a much lower value. Usually, I put the value to **0.00 MM** and check if this solves the issue.

If this removes the blank page, try finding the margin that is the real cause, by entering the margin values one by one.

If there is **blank page** after each page. This probably will be your solution.

The same issue will cause adding **blank space** on top of the report page after page, if 'keep together' option is not ticked in 'Section expert' for 'details'.