# Details Section of Crystal Report printing blank on first page

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report which is printing the details section of the first page as blank. (Page header and Footer present) But from pages 2 onwards it is printing the correct information.
So basically the details information is starting on page 2 and not on page one.

This only occurs in cases where the details section cannot fit within one page and has to be continued printed on different pages.

However if my details can fit on one page there is no such issue and prints correctly on Page one itself.

Answer (score 0):

Count how many records can fit into first page and what's the critical point of records when they have to start from second page. After that enter that amount into `Section Expert` of `Details Section` (selected red on picture) or write a procedure in that trigger (for example if count of records > than x value then true else false or something similar). 
[image]

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue because of the "Keep Object Together" settings on the section expert of the Detail Section. You can change the same, uncheck the checkbox and this will print some of the section.

Follow the link below, and check if that helps you.

[Avoid Blank page Issue in Crystal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22175048/crystal-reports-printing-blank-page)